# duplicate log entries Nlog

Tags: logging, nlog

I use Nlog to log and i find that i have 5 entries in my log file for every call made to nLog. How can i fix it?
for eg.

```
2012-12-23 18:18:19.2465 NinjaTrader.Strategy.LODHOD.OnStartUp Debug   startup
2012-12-23 18:18:19.2465 NinjaTrader.Strategy.LODHOD.OnStartUp Debug   startup
2012-12-23 18:18:19.2465 NinjaTrader.Strategy.LODHOD.OnStartUp Debug   startup
2012-12-23 18:18:19.2465 NinjaTrader.Strategy.LODHOD.OnStartUp Debug   startup
2012-12-23 18:18:19.2465 NinjaTrader.Strategy.LODHOD.OnStartUp Debug   startup
2012-12-23 18:18:19.2465 NinjaTrader.Strategy.LODHOD.OnStartUp Debug   startup
```

My nLog config is as below

```cs
/****CLASS LEVEL VARIABLES***/
// Step 1. Create configuration object 
private static LoggingConfiguration config = new LoggingConfiguration();
private static FileTarget fileTarget = new FileTarget();
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
/*** END OF CLASS LEVEL VARIABLES ***/

/*************************NLOG CONFIG*****/

fileTarget.FileName = 
  "C:\\temp\\" + Instrument.FullName + "nLog." + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".log";
fileTarget.Layout = 
  "${longdate} ${callsite} ${level} ${event-context:item=StrategyId}  ${message}";

config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

// Step 4. Define rules
LoggingRule rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget);
config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

// Step 5. Activate the configuration
LogManager.Configuration = config;


logger.Debug("startup");


/*************************NLOG CONFIG*****/
```

you can see the starup printed 6 times and it is called only once in the program at the begining of the program in the Ninjatrader onStartup.

I also have the scoped Global Diagnistoc but i dont think that can cause this to happen

```cs
public class ScopedGlobalContext : IDisposable
{
  private string n;
  private string v;

  public ScopedGlobalContext(string name, string value)
  {
    n = name;
    v = value;
    NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set(n, v);
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Remove(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: As your rule is called rule2, do you have multiple ones?

Comment: no. that is all the code that i have for nLog. i deleted the rule1 but forgot to rename the variables. I am still not sure why it gets printed 6 times

Comment: Do you have any NLog configuration, either in app.config or in NLog.config?  Have you posted all of your NLog configuration code?  I see you have a variable, "config", where does it come from?

Comment: these are just class level variables that i was using. i cut and pasted it in the code sample that i have shown.

Comment: In the first code block you have a section (as noted in the comments) called "CLASS LEVEL VARIABLES".  Do you have this same code in each class?  I ask this because, you should configure NLog exactly once in your application, not once per class.  Have you tried making a stripped down program/library to experiment with NLog?  It might be easier to figure out what is going on with NLog if you have less stuff going on.

Comment: i use them in only 1 class and they are declared in the same class as static. I will try a small program later this weekend and figure out why i get duplicates.

Comment: I commented the ScopedGlobalContext class and the duplicates went away. I am not sure why it was causing duplicates.

Comment: Are you running in different threads.

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple rules that targets for instance file, then you get multiple writes to it.

Comment: This thread in the nlog forum suggests to use 'final' to prevent this: http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/Duplicate-log-entries-caused-by-duplicate-rules-td6587621.html

Answer (score 4):

In my case, marking the rules as `final` solved the issue.

```
<rules>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn"  appendTo="database" final="true"/>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal" appendTo="database" final="true"/>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" appendTo="database" final="true"/>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Info"  appendTo="database" final="true"/>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" appendTo="database" final="true"/>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" appendTo="database" final="true"/>
</rules>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing happen to me. Several searches lead to other people having the same issue, but no solution. I think this is a bug that happens if you're running multiple threads and/or if code doing the logging is being called by a Linq query. Remember, Linq does not always execute immediately or once.

Comment: The real question is why would you log inside of a linq query?  Logging is a side effect so if being done in a linq query causes the linq statement to be evaluated locally.  If you need a foreach, use a foreach.  Don't hack a Select.  It's like using Tap in RxJs.  Outside of debugging purposes, it's bad practice.

Comment: No. I don't mean the actual linq methods, but any object methods that you invoke using them, say "select p from Object.GetItems()" where GetItems() performs Logs itself.

Answer (score 1):

[WhenRepeated-Filter](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WhenRepeated-Filter)

> Matches when the calculated layout has already been logged. Useful if having an aggressive logger, and wants to throttle the output.
>
> Introduced with NLog ver. 4.5

It looks to be the solution introduced by nlog to debounce/throttle log outputs.

Comment: WhenRepeated-Filter is a work-around for bad logging behavior in the host-application. It is not meant as work-around for wrongly configured NLog logging-rules (Better just to fix the logging-rule config)

Answer (score 0):

adding final attribute to logger solved my issue

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="log" final="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

NLog.Web.AspNetCore v4.8.6 [changes registration of NLog Logging Provider](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/485), so one is now allowed to call both `AddNLog` and `UseNLog` without experiencing double logging.

NLog 5.0 implements [validation of incorrect duplicate target configuration](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/4354), so one will not experience double logging when using incorrect NLog configuration (Will also notify in [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging))